# What to check when finding a replacement disk

Tags: hard-drive

I have recently joined a company where we provide hardware support. Often we have to replace hard disks for servers (Dell/IBM) and the hdd models that were used when the servers were built are no longer available.
My question is when finding a replacement disk, what do you check? I generally check storage size, speed (rpm), form factor (2.5/3.5). Do we have to ensure that transfer speed (Gbps) also matches? What else do we have to check? Is there any online utility that can help?

Also do we have to match cache?

Comment: You should also check that the new disc does not consume more power, unless  you are certain that the power supply and ventilation have plenty of reserve capacity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Interface* is essential - Newer systems use SAS,SATA or various flavours of NVMe (and while some SAS interfaces will let you use sata drives). Older machines may use PATA(aka IDE) or various flavours of SCSI, many of which have incompatible connectors.

Storage size isn't that important (get enough!) *but* some interfaces may have limits on disk size on extremely old machines. Its an edge case unless you're using a machine from the turn of the century. Its worth checking to see if there's an OS or hardware limitation - these should be in the appropriate manuals or documentation.

With *sata*, transfer speed is often used as a shorthand for the revision (sata 2, 3). With SSDs you may be able to saturate an older version (or even a newer one). That said, you can likely happily replace a sata 2 drive with a sata 3 drive with no issues. You can likely go the other way, but its easier to find a newer drive than a new old stock (or pulled) sata 2 drive.

However with SAS, SAS 6gb and SAS 12gb have different *physical interfaces*

SCSI is a complete mess with half a dozen varients, completely different connectors and other confusing things.

*Rotational speed* affects performance and heat *somewhat* - that said, outside laptops, shouldn't matter all that much. It certainly wouldn't stop you from running a hard drive.

Its also worth considering 'server' 2.5 inch drives have much deeper z height and arn't the same as laptop 2.5 inch drives. Laptop 2.5 drives have 3 or so z heights - 5 7 and 9 inches IIRC and you can fit a thinner drive into a thicker bay, but not vice versa.

Cache dosen't affect compatibility. More cache is good on hard drives (more fast, nearby storage means better performance) and on SSDs *but* you don't need to match when replacing.

Answer (score 2):

I previously worked as a technician in electronic recycling operation, so this question is right down my alley.

One of the things you should be aware is that the **firmware** on each drive can also prove to be very important. As I'm aware there is no table to directly map which company's firmware will work with a particular drive controller. Working with older brand name servers such as IBM, Dell, and HP proved that one generation might have some very strict controls on this, where as the next did not. RAM frequency/buffering/parity was the same way, but was tied more to the chipset used rather then a third-party controller.

**Drive height**, the height if you were to place the drive on the top of a table, and measure the vertical distance, can also prove to be a topic of concern. While 3.5" drives don't tend to have such an issue, 2.5" drives are notorious for this. These smaller drives can come in 9mm or 7.5mm commonly, so replacing a 7.5mm with 9mm might run you into a world of pain.

One of the easier things to manage were the **I/O connectors**. SCSI-320 came in two major forms, one with a female connector vs. a male connection. Finding replacement drives were a pain if a retailer failed to specified a manufacturer replacement part number, connector type (of the how many there are), the transfer rate, and others.

SATA/SAS drives have significantly less pain, as the only key part to remember is that (most of the time) a SATA drive will plug into a SAS backplane where as the opposite is not true. You can observe this with the physical connectors. Transfer rates, firmware, spindle speed, and all that tend to be less of a concern (if any). *SAS has started to come in it's 12Gb variety*, which is only seen in modern servers. I also remember there was one brand that also had two separate connector interfaces on each drive.

**Drive caddies/trays** (presuming rack servers) are something you should look at as well. Dell has at least 3 different types that I'm aware of, and IBM with 2. Matching these up can be hard if you don't physically handle the different drives/brands on a regular basis.

Comment: Ah yeah, and some companies won't honor warranties without *their* disks, and or will warn you.